# How can I remove image attributes in html code

Tags: c#, asp.net, function

I need to make an ASP.net C# function for removing **all** image attributes, except "src", "align", "alt" and "title". The function must **only** remove content inside image tags. The input is html used for displaying articles, where I need to clean up image attributes.

```
public static string FixImageAttributes(string html-string)
{
    // Remove all attribues in the html-string here, except: "src", "align", "alt" and "title".

    return html-string;
}
```

**Example:**

If function input (html-string) is this:

```
<html>
<body>
<div>
<h1>Some html here</h1>
<p><img align="right" title="" border="0" hspace="7" alt="" vspace="7" src="/upload/content/images/bla/bla/test.jpg"></p>
</div>
<div>
<h2>Lorem impum</h2>
<p><img src="/upload/content/test/blah/image.jpg" width="624" height="255" alt="Text here" title="Hello" border="0" vspace="0" hspace="0"></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The function output should be this:

```
<html>
<body>
<div>
<h1>Some html here</h1>
<p><img align="right" title="" alt="" src="/upload/content/images/bla/bla/test.jpg"></p>
</div>
<div>
<h2>Lorem impum</h2>
<p><img src="/upload/content/test/blah/image.jpg" alt="Text here" title="Hello"></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified [Ran Turner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69285628/12351609) a bit:

```
public static string RemoveAllAttributesFromImgNode(string html)
{
    var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
    htmlDocument.LoadHtml(html);
    string[] filter  = { "src", "align", "alt", "title" };
    var nodes = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img");
    foreach (var node in nodes)
    {
        var attributes = node.Attributes.Where(x => !filter.Contains(x.Name.ToString())).ToList();
        foreach (var attribute in attributes)
        {
            node.Attributes.Remove(attribute);
        }
    }
    html = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
    return html;
}
```

Output from console:

```
Old HTML:

<html>
<body>
<div>
<h1>Some html here</h1>
<p>
<img align="right" title="" border="0" hspace="7" alt="" vspace="7" src="/upload/content/images/bla/bla/test.jpg">
</p>
</div>
<div>
<h2> Lorem impum</h2 >
<p>
<img src="/upload/content/test/blah/image.jpg" width="624" height="255" alt="Text here" title ="Hello" border="0" vspace="0" hspace="0">
</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>

===============================

New HTML:

<html>
<body>
<div>
<h1>Some html here</h1>
<p>
<img align="right" title="" alt="" src="/upload/content/images/bla/bla/test.jpg">
</p>
</div>
<div>
<h2> Lorem impum</h2>
<p>
<img src="/upload/content/test/blah/image.jpg" alt="Text here" title="Hello">
</p>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: That worked perfect, thank you so much!! Just wonder about one additional thing: Is it easy to add a parameter to each image if it not excist? Ex: If a image not have a 'class' parameter, add 'class="img-fluid"'.

Comment: It is possible, try using node.Attributes.Add("class", "img-fluid").

Comment: If you could, mark the answer as correct so the question will be closed. Upvotes are useful as well ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HtmlAgilityPack` for this and write something like this:

```
public string RemoveAllAttributesFromEveryNode(string html)
{
    var htmlDocument = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    htmlDocument.LoadHtml(html);
    var filterList = new List<string>{"src", "align", "alt", "title"};
    
    foreach (var node in htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*"))
    {
       var toRemove = node.Attributes.Where(x => !filterList.Contains(x)).ToList();
       foreach (var attribute in toRemove)
       {
           attribute.Remove();
       }
    }

    html = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;

    return html;
}
```

More about can be found here `HtmlAgilityPack` can be found here:

https://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex

Comment: I get "The name 'item' does not exist in the current context". How to fix that? I guess 'node.Attributes.Where' should be 'eachNode.Attributes.Where'? Is this code only processing image tags (<img>)? If not, how to fix that? Thanks for all help :)

Comment: My bad. Try now

Comment: Thanks. Now I only get "The name 'node' does not exist in the current context". If I change 'node' to 'eachNode', I get "Cannot convert from 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlAttribute or string' on "x". Should I change to x.ToString() as well?

Comment: Try again. Fixed

Comment: filterList.Contains(x) gives this error: cannot convert from 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlAttribute' to 'string'

Comment: If I change to x.ToString() the code don't fail, but the image is removed (not only the parameters).

Comment: I gave you a general script using HtmlAgilityPack.. You can modify the script to your case.